# How to creat a dynamic RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to match some words in a string. But I don't have a predefined number of words I need to find.

For example I search for `Ubuntu 18 10` in `ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent` would return true.

Or I could search for `centos 7` in `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804.torrent` would also return true.

I don't need to check if it's lowercase or not.

What I tried :

```
$.get('interdit', function(data) {
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    $.each(lines, function(n, data_interdit) {
        var url_check = $('textarea#url').val()
        var split_forbidden = data_interdit.split(/[\s|,|_|.|-|:]+/);
        var exist = 0;
        $.each(split_forbidden, function(n, data) {
            var n = url_check.search("^("+ data +")");
            if(n != -1){
                exist = 1
            }else{
                exist = 0
            }
            console.log('Forbidden: '+ data + ' Result: ' + n);
        })
        if(exist == 1){
            console.log('found')
        }
    });
});
```

Sample data of the file **interdit** :

```
CentOS.7
Ubuntu-18
```

Comment: You can use the regexp constructor if you have to use dynamic regexp over string manipulation: `new RegExp()`. But the strings you are trying to match are kind of irregular, making a regular expression somewhat less desirable.

Comment: what is your keywords that need to search for? Maybe you dont need a dynamic regex maybe you just need a token splitter to split the tokens and return the OS keyword

Comment: It can be anything even something else than an OS. In my script I split my search word and I loop in throught the string

Comment: Do you want to allow only one character in place of space that could be anything?

Comment: @revo You mean in the splitting part ?

Comment: I mean hear `Ubuntu 18 10`.

Comment: It can be also another splitting character. That's why I use this reg to split `/[\s,_.-:]+/`. In this case It need to match `Ubuntu` and `18` and `10` to be valid

Comment: I don't read your solution. I'm trying to understand the question. You are going to put `Ubuntu 18 10` and want to be able to have a match in `ubuntu-18.10` this means the regex should be e.g. `/Ubuntu.18.10/i`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that it's correct

Comment: Should `Ubuntu 18 10` produce a match in `ubuntu--18.10` or `ubuntu-X-18.10` too?

Comment: Yep that's right

Comment: What if the input string is `10-18.ubuntu`? Is order counted?

Comment: Order doesn't count.

Comment: Check this https://jsbin.com/vokepazada/edit?js,console

Comment: The code doesn't find when there is a `:` separator

Comment: Split on `[\s,_.:-]+` instead of `\s+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look for existing words within the input string without the order being taken into account. You need to use positive lookaheads for this:

```js
var search = 'Ubuntu 18 10';
var str = 'ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent';
var re = new RegExp('^(?=.*' + search.split(/[\s,_.:-]+/).join(')(?=.*') + ')', 'i')

console.log(re.test(str));
```

This produces a regex as the following (with `i` flag set):

```
^(?=.*Ubuntu)(?=.*18)(?=.*10)
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `Invalid regular expression: /^(?=.**centos*)/: Nothing to repeat`. If in my file I have the following `*centos*`

Comment: You should escape all special characters before passing it to constructor. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex).

Comment: Well I have a new error https://i.imgur.com/HgSTrXu.png and my search string contain `*ubuntu*` in this case

Comment: Please provide a live demo. I can't find from where `\)` is added in your regex. It should be `)` with no backslashes.

Comment: I created a jsbin here https://jsbin.com/tezejicugi/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Don't you think you should add `*` beside other characters in split method regex? otherwise what should regex look for?

Comment: Well I added this part of code to remove the first and last character `search = search .substring(1, search .length-1);`

Comment: Please check my answer at your other question.

Comment: Can I ask how to make the order to be taken into account

Answer (score 1):

## RegEx Array

### Update

> *"The code give me an error [jsbin.com/pecoleweyi/2/edit?js,console](http://jsbin.com/pecoleweyi/2/edit?js,console)"*

Although the question did not include unlikely input such as: `*centos 7*`, add the following line to escape the special characters that occur in input:

```
var esc = word.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/gi, '\\$&');
```

and change the next line:

```
var sub = esc.replace(/\s/gi, '.');
```

The demo below will:

- accept a string (`str`) to search and an array of strings (`tgt`) to find within the string,
- `.map()` the array (`tgt`) which will run a function on each string (`word`)
- escape any special characters:

  ```
  var esc = word.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/gi, '\\$&');
  ```
- replace any spaces (`/\s/g`) with a dot (`.`):

  ```
  var sub = esc.replace(/\s/g, '.');
  ```
- then makes a `RegExp()` Object so a variable can be inserted in the pattern via template literal interpolation (say that ten times fast):

  ```
  var rgx = new RegExp(`${sub}`, `gim`);
  ```
- uses `.test()` to get a boolean: found = `true` / not found = `false`

  ```
  var bool = rgx.test(str);
  ```
- create an Object to assign the search string: `word` as a property and the boolean: `bool` as it's value.

  ```
  var obj = {
    [word]: bool
  };
  ```
- returns an array of objects:

  ```
  [{"centos 7":true},{"Ubuntu 18 10":true}]
  ```

---

### Demo

```js
var str = `ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent 
CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804.torrent`;

var tgt = [`centos 7`, `Ubuntu 18 10`, `corn flakes`, `gnome`, `Red Hat`, `*centos 7*`];

function rgxArray(str, tgt) {
  var res = tgt.map(function(word) {
    var esc = word.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/gi, '\\$&');
    var sub = esc.replace(/\s/gi, '.');
    var rgx = new RegExp(`${sub}`, `gi`);
    var bool = rgx.test(str);
    var obj = {
      [word]: bool
    };
    return obj;
  });
  return res;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(rgxArray(str, tgt)));
```

Comment: The code give me an error https://jsbin.com/pecoleweyi/2/edit?js,console

Comment: @executable escape the special characters of input, see update.