# Match strings in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have made a regex, but I can't make it to match in order.

```js
var $result = [];
var url_check = "CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804";
var torrent_forbidden = ["CentOS-7 live", "Centos 7 livegnome", "Cent-7", "OS Cent-7", "centos:7", "centos word:7", "centos:6", "cento 7 s"];
jQuery.each(torrent_forbidden , function(index, torrent_forbidden) { 
    var regex = new RegExp('^(?=.*?' + torrent_forbidden.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&').split(/\\?[\s,_.:*-]+/).join(')(?=.*?') + ')', 'gi');
    if(regex.test(url_check) === true){
        $result.push(torrent_forbidden + ' : true');
    }else{
        $result.push(torrent_forbidden + ' : false');
    }
});
console.log($result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is what I expect to obtain as result in the string `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804`:

```
|-----------------------------------------|
| Search             | Result | Expected  |
|-----------------------------------------|
| CentOS-7 live      | true   | false     |
| Centos 7 livegnome | true   | true      |
| Cent-7             | true   | false     |
| OS Cent-7          | true   | false     |
| centos:7           | true   | true      |
| centos word:7      | false  | false     |
| centos:6           | true   | false     |
| cento 7 s          | true   | false     |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

Comment: It's the orginal string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53945019/2813224

Comment: This does not meet my requirements

Comment: Why would you expect `centos:7` to be true?

Comment: Did you see the regex you're creating? I don't get why `centos:7` is expected to be found in that string, propably you should set some requirements, and create proper regexes

Comment: I consider `:` only has a separator

Comment: `^(?=.*?' +...` A lookahead needs a pattern before it...and how is `Centos 7 livegnome` true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating regexes from strings like `^(?=.*?CentOS)(?=.*?7)(?=.*?live)` which searches for given words. It lacks some restrictions, like:

- this word can be followed only by `-` (or some other separator) or end of string
- this word should be at beginning of the string or after `-` (or some other separator)

So, you need to create lookahead like:

```
(?=^(.*separators)?someword(separators|$))
```

instead of:

```
(?=.*?someword)
```

(For `-` as separator it would be: `(?=^(.*[-])?someword([-]|$))`)

```js
var $result = [];
var url_check = "CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804";
var torrent_forbidden = ["CentOS-7 live", "Centos 7 livegnome", "Cent-7", "OS Cent-7", "centos:7", "centos word:7", "centos:6", "cento 7 s", "entOS-7", "*centos*"];
jQuery.each(torrent_forbidden , function(index, torrent_forbidden) { 
   var regexstr = '^(?=^(.*[-])?' + torrent_forbidden.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&').split(/\\?[\s,_.:*-]+/).join('([-]|$))(?=^(.*[-])?') + '([-]|$))';
   console.log(regexstr)
    var regex = new RegExp(regexstr, 'gi');
    if(regex.test(url_check) === true){
        $result.push(torrent_forbidden + ' : true');
    }else{
        $result.push(torrent_forbidden + ' : false');
    }
});
console.log($result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the logic behind: `Centos 7 livegnome : true"`?

Comment: @zer00ne string "CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804" contains words "Centos", "7" and "livegnome" (it's case insensitive)

Comment: Little issue, if I search like `entOS-7` it will be true

Comment: @executable then add condition that it has to start with `-` or start of string

Comment: What is the meaning of `-` ?

Comment: @executable it's character `-` that seems to be separator for words in your string (for what I understand you can match only words in array `url_check.split('-')` )

Comment: I use this to separate `split(/\\?[\s,_.:*-]+/)`

Comment: @executable I added regex for start of word, hope you're capable of replacing `-` with list of separators you need

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong `var regex = new RegExp('^(?=^(.*[\s,_.:*-])?' + torrent_forbidden.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&').split(/\\?[\s,_.:*-]+/).join('([\s,_.:*-]|$))(?=^(.*[\s,_.:*-])?') + '([\s,_.:*-]|$))', 'gi');`

Comment: @executable seems fine

Comment: I tested with `*centos*`, it seems like it doesn't split the `*`, I expect it to be true

Comment: @executable `torrent_forbidden.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&').split(/\\?[\s,_.:*-]+/)` results in ["", "centos", ""], you need to remove empty strings from that array before `join`

Comment: Alright, I ade this `var regexstr = '^(?=^(.*[\s,_.:*-])?' + torrent_interdit.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&').split(/\\?[\s,_.:*-]+/).filter(function(e){ return e.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")}).join('([\s,_.:*-]|$))(?=^(.*[\s,_.:*-])?') + '([\s,_.:*-]|$))'` It look like it's working

Comment: @executable it's really worth to create string first, and then pass it to `RegExp` so that you could debug it and see what it contains

Comment: You mean to decompose the regex ?

Comment: I made some more test and it seems like it doesn't check in order. https://jsbin.com/qosafihabo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: No, it searches for each word separately - as your regex did. Look, you didn't wrote any requirements, included some code you obtained in other question and keep writing "look I've found yet another case I wanted to cover". And that jsbin lacks even dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution, it might not be perfect but you should precise more your requirements it it fails in some cases. The regex will test if the words are in order and separated by the separators (if not at beginning or end). It will match entire words (`x86` will be detected but not `x8`). There can be words between those specified. Some explanations:

- positive lookaheads don't consume characters, so i don't think you can combine them to guarantee an order, il will only guarantee that they will be present afterwards
- you should use double escaping `\\` if you build a RegExp from a string
- no need to use `filter` to do another `replace` (it was in the duplicate post) -> EDIT: restored because it has another function: removing empty strings
- you can use `?:` to make a group for an alternative that doesn't capture, or if you want to quantify a group
- if you have other questions about the regex, just ask..

```js
var $result = [];
var url_check = "CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804";
var torrent_forbidden = ["CentOS-7 live", "Centos 7 livegnome", "Cent-7", "OS Cent-7", "centos:7", "centos word:7", "centos:6", "cento 7 s", "CentOS x86", "CentOS x8", "*CentOS*"];
jQuery.each(torrent_forbidden , function(index, torrent_forbidden) { 
    var regexstr = '(?:^|[\\s,_.:*-])' + torrent_forbidden
      .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
      .split(/\\?[\s,_.:*-]+/)
      .filter( function(e){ return e.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); } )
      .join('(?:(?:[\\s,_.:*-][^\\s,_.:*-]+)+)?[\\s,_.:*-]') + '(?:[\\s,_.:*-]|$)';
    console.log(regexstr); //To debug your regexes
    var regex = new RegExp(regexstr, 'gi');
    if(regex.test(url_check) === true){
        $result.push(torrent_forbidden + ' : true');
    }else{
        $result.push(torrent_forbidden + ' : false');
    }
});
console.log($result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer ! I'll make some testing

Comment: I found an issue, if my search value is like `*centos*`. I think it's because we don't remove the empty string and the `filter` function corrected that issue

Comment: You're right, i restored the filter. I find strange that it should be a positive result because it has `*` at the beginning while the file has nothing before `CentOS`, but that would require changes to take that in account

Comment: I think it's because it didn't escape so it break the regular expression. So we can't detect in the order of the filename ?